# In a genetic algorithm is roulette wheel selection the same as Monte Carlo method?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

After reading a [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21526157) they mention the Monte Carlo method for selecting fittest chromosomes. Is this the same as [roulette wheel selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection)?

Direct quote

> The same initial population of individuals was used for each problem and architecture. The population sizes were 150 individuals (except for HD problem that was 100). The following techniques were employed: the Montecarlo method for the selection of individuals; the Darwinian substitution method; a single crossover point; a crossover rate of 90%; and a mutation rate of 10%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.9494) by Goldberg & Deb (1991). In it they have also mentioned the term Monte Carlo, exact sentence is (Page 3: Section "Proportionate Reproduction"):

> ... Various methods have been suggested for sampling this probability
>   distribution, including **Monte Carlo or roulette wheel selection** (De
>   Jong, 1975), stochastic remainder selection (Booker, 1982; Brindle,
>   1981).....

So I suspect the term Monte Carlo was used to denote they used the method to generate a random number as a part of the selection process, rather than using it solely for selection.

If you remember computers back in the day needed a good random number generator, so they could have been using Monte Carlo for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this is a typo. Monte Carlo isn't even correctly spelled, so there doesn't seem to have been much proofreading there. I've never heard of a Monte Carlo method to select the individuals. It would mean we select them randomly, which doesn't sound like a good idea:  unlike Monte Carlo, a genetic algorithm does its search purposefully. The roulette wheel selection, for example, is biased toward the individuals that have the highest fitness. Note that we could use Monte Carlo when computing the fitness though. In any case, regarding the paper, I would ignore the mention the Monte Carlo method for selecting the individuals, or email the authors if I need the information.

Comment: Well I do kind of need to know because I am re-implementing their algorithm. I have tried contacting the authors but they have not been helpful unfortunately. How could we use MC to calculate fitness? And as a separate questions do you know what they mean by Darwinian substitution?

Comment: > _they have not been helpful unfortunately._ What did they say?
> How could we use MC to calculate fitness? E.g. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0951832099000800 "for each proposed chromosome, one can run a Monte Carlo code with a limited number of trials, e.g. 500, obtaining poorly significant statistical results."

Comment: > _Darwinian substitution?_ No idea! I don't see what substitution they are talking about. Maybe they just refer loosely to the fact that they create a new generation with some individuals from the last generation + some new newly created individuals. I guess that's another question for them (and I'm also curious to know what they say about it).

Comment: yeah thats what i thought as well. Well actually, i didn't ask them that specific question but i asked them many others about their algorithm. (If you look closely at their algorithm it seems like their m processing iterations per sample can be reduced to one calculation and they are unclear about which weights astrocyte modify, among other things!) I had to call them to get them to respond to my email to which they gave short unhelpful one sentence answers like "Depends on the algorithm". So I don't think I'll get much more out of them than that!!

Comment: We really need open science... academic research is so inefficient that way it is right now. Anyway, maybe you could try to ask them the source code if they don't have the time to answer to your specific questions?

Comment: Also asked for the source code but they said no! And couldn't agree more. I have an idea for an open science site, a project I will work on this summer when I get a moment...

Comment: Geez not cool! Are they aware they have been funded with our money? Nice way to fabricate results safely.
_The work was supported by grants from Ministry of Science and Innovation of Spain (TIN2009-07707, BFU2010-15832, CSD2010-00045), Xunta de Galicia, Spain (REGICC 2009/58, 08SIN010105PR), CYTED (Ibero-NBIC Network 209RT0366), Cajal Blue Brain, Spain, and European Union (HEALTH-F2-2007-202167). The funders had no role in study design, data collection and analysis, decision to publish, or preparation of the manuscript._

Comment: Please consider my answer, as I believe my answer to be more correct :)